# How to make a StringVar with multiple colors in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, colors

Let's say we have a `StringVar`:

```
string_var = tk.StringVar(value="Red, Blue")
string_var.configure(fg='red')
```

Is it possible to configure this StringVar so that 'Red' will be colored red, and 'Blue' will be colored blue?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Instances of `StringVar` and the other tkinter variables don't have a visual representation.

The best option for text with multiple colors is to use a `Text` or `Canvas` widget. Both of those have the ability to add color to groups of text.